# How to solve res.status is not a function?

Tags: node.js

When I query the url localhost:3000/practice. I have error **res.status is not function.**
I wanna have functions in other file named UserControllers

```
var userControllers = {
    home: function (res, req) {
        return res.status(200).send({
            message: 'practice'    
        })
    }
}
module.exports = userControllers
```

**The url 'localhost:3000/home' is working but the url 'localhost:3000/practice' is not working!**

```
var { Router } = require('express')
var userControllers = require('./Controllers/UserControllers')
var router = Router();

router.get('/home', function(req, res){
    res.send('home!')
});

router.get('/practice', userControllers.home)

module.exports  = router
```

Comment: Function parameter order matters. The express ``req`` object comes first, ***then*** the express ``res`` object.

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes thanks!!